# Images in Slider are not full width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the images in the slider to be full width or responsive.

The HTML is here on [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/ek8sYwGJ)

```
<div class="main-slider slider-pro" id="main-slider" data-slider-width="100%" data-slider-height="850px" data-slider-arrows="true" data-slider-buttons="true">
    <div class="sp-slides">
    <!-- Slide 1-->
        <div class="sp-slide">
            <img class="sp-image" data-large="assets/media/components/b-main-slider/bg-1.jpg" src="assets/media/components/b-main-slider/bg-2.jpg" alt="slider" />
             <div class="container">
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                         <div class="main-slider__info sp-layer" data-width="100%" data-show-transition="left" data-hide-transition="left" data-show-duration="2000" data-show-delay="1200" data-hide-delay="1200">welcome to koka</div>
                         <div class="main-slider__title sp-layer" data-width="100%" data-show-transition="left" data-hide-transition="left" data-show-duration="2000" data-show-delay="1200" data-hide-delay="1200">

                             <div class="typed-strings">

                                 <ul>
                                     <li>welcome to <span class="main-slider__title-emphasis">WELCOME</span></li>
                                     <li>PROFITABLE <span class="main-slider__title-emphasis">DIGITAL MARKETING</span></li>
                                 </ul>

                              </div>

                          </div>

                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

Basically the images from the slider are shown only on the left side (70% of the slide). While in the right side of the slide, there is an empty space. (30%)

Comment: Could you create a working demo for us? In JsFiddle for example.. ?

Comment: Please provide a working example. You can use jsfiddle.net for that. Please include your css, the html and maybe your js code.

Comment: The website I'm working on is here: http://www.kdm.ro/kokadigital/ - you can see the slider with images.